# jquery reset all input fields in array

Tags: jquery

I have a select field and function to hide/show divs. Inside those divs are input fields that I want to reset each time a different selection is made.

This script clears fields as long as I specify each field ID.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Main_Connection").change(function(){
    $('#InputFieldID').val("");
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

But I also made this script to get all the field IDs, which I *think* works because it shows all the IDs in the browser debugger.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
    var AllFields = $("[id^=Main_] input");
    console.log(i, "Hello, world!");
    });
</script>
```

Simply changing `$('#InputFieldID').val("");` to `$('#AllFields').val("");` does not work. How can I get my first script to reset each field found by the second script?

Comment: can you show the html here? I'm note sure what your fields are named. You shouldn't have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: If your jQuery selector properly selects all the `<input>` fields to be cleared, this should clear them: `$("[id^=Main_] input").val('')`.

Comment: Thanks @kmoser, it was that simple. Unfortunately I cannot mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: @sjaak I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jQuery selector properly selects all the `<input>` fields to be cleared, this should clear them:

```
$("[id^=Main_] input").val('')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is 100% what you are looking for , but :
try using `each` around all the IDs as follows :

```
$("[id^=Main_] input").each(function() {
     $(this).val("");
 });
```